# How to convert a column that has fractions to decimals in python

Tags: python

DataFrame example :

| ID | Rule | Postion |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1233 | M-4/32 | 516.00 |
| 1235 | M-8/32 | 716.00 |
| 1236 | M-2/32 | 816.00 |

I need to split the Rule column which I tried to handle with:

`DataFrame['effective date'] = DataFrame['Rule'].str.split(expand=True)`

However this is not working the way I expected.

From there I need to convert the fraction portion of the rule column to a decimal and I cant figure out how.

If I can get the str.split function to work the way I need the conversion of the fraction should be straight forward.

Expected results:

| ID | Rule | Postion | Rule Final |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1233 | M-4/32 | 516.00 | 0.125 |
| 1235 | M-8/32 | 716.00 | 0.25 |
| 1236 | M-2/32 | 816.00 | 0.0625 |

Comment: show what results do you expect

Comment: `split()` will split on `space`,`tab`,`enter`. You have to add char which it has to use for split

Comment: What dataframe library are you using, Pandas? Please add the tag for it. If you are, btw, the name `DataFrame` is confusing since *UpperCamelCase* should be reserved for class names. `df` is the standard name for demos and the like.

Answer (score 2):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1233], 'Rule': ['M-4/32'], 'Postion': [516.00]})
df['effective date'] = df['Rule'].str.split('-', expand=True)[1]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     ID    Rule  Postion effective date
0  1233  M-4/32    516.0           4/32
```

If you want to go further and try to convert the string fraction into a float number:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': [1233], 'Rule': ['M-4/32'], 'Postion': [516.00]})
df['effective date'] = df['Rule'].str.split('-', expand=True)[1]
df.loc[df['effective date'].apply(lambda x: set(x) <= set('1234567890./')), 'effective date'] = df.loc[df['effective date'].apply(lambda x: set(x) <= set('1234567890./')), 'effective date'].apply(eval)
print(df)
```

The output:

```
     ID    Rule  Postion  effective date
0  1233  M-4/32    516.0           0.125
```

The condition `.apply(lambda x: set(x) <= set('1234567890./'))` was added, because otherwise the built-in function `eval()` is extremely dangerous.

Comment: OP wants decimals so it will need extra code to convert `4/32` to `0.125` - or at least `.apply(eval)`

Comment: @furas, exactly. But OP had written: "If I can get the str.split function to work the way I need the conversion of the fraction should be straight forward." So I didn't touch upon that. Moreover the actual file may have rows that violate this pattern and contain integers instead of the fractions, so my improvisation might miserably fail.

Comment: Thanks for responding. furas is correct I need to figure out how to convert the fractions to decimals also.

Comment: Ok. I added it to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal = []
for rule in DataFrame['Rule']:
    parts = rule.split("-")
    decimal_pts = parts[1].split("/")
    decimal.append(float(decimal_pts[0])/float(decimal_pts[1]))
DataFrame['effective date'] = decimal
```

Comment: The data frame has multiple rows. With the code above I get this error: File "<ipython-input-50-783f9b8ee860>", line 4, in <module> decimal_pts = parts[1].split("/") IndexError: list index out of range Any Way around this?